# Exit script if a service fails

Tags: bash

I want to stop the execution of my bash script if a certain service fails to run.

```
systemctl is-active --quiet nginx || (echo "Nginx couldn't be started...exiting" && exit)
```

I do get the `Nginx couldn't be started...exiting` message but my script continues running.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

> What am I doing wrong here?

`( command-list )` means *run command-list in a subshell*, and calling `exit` from within a subshell doesn't make the parent exit. Use curly braces,

```
systemctl is-active --quiet nginx || { echo "Nginx couldn't be started...exiting"; exit; }
```

or an if-block instead.

```
if ! systemctl is-active --quiet nginx; then
  echo "Nginx couldn't be started...exiting"
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis create a subshell, meaning the exit call just exits from the subshell.